# Run jQuery function on update of div's HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have the following AJAX call to a file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: readfile.txt,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    };
});
```

It appends the contents of the readfile.txt to the #content div. This is working properly.

What I want to do, is to scroll to the bottom of the div, every time the content is changed. Currently I have the following:

```
$('#content').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    $('#content').animate({scrollTop: $('#content').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
});
```

The animate function is working properly, however it isn't being triggered when the html of the #content div is changed. Is there a better way to listed for html change events?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could trigger the event manually in your success function.  Is that an option?

Comment: I think your code is actually working as is except for the animation: http://jsfiddle.net/vxudjx1o/

Comment: Sorry for all the comment spam.  Your listener should be working.  The only thing I can think of is that the animate is being run a bunch of times which causes it to take forever.  Try adding `.stop()` to your animation to ensure it only runs once. http://jsfiddle.net/vxudjx1o/1/.  (note that in my demo, I changed the scroll to the body just for demonstration purposes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the animation to your success callback

```
$.ajax({
    url: readfile.txt,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data).animate({scrollTop: $('#content').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
    };
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it ;) but yeah this is the most simple approach for the problem. although I would probably cache $('#content') if it were used more often

Comment: Unfortunately that is only the base of the ajax call, and when I add it to the success function, it breaks the functionality. Should have mentioned that in the post though.

Your answer is correct based on the information I gave so I'll mark it as right, issue is still here though :(

Comment: Try using just the `DOMSubtreeModified` event